# Why can't I export the apk file from Eclipse when I turn on ProGuard?

Tags: android, proguard

> [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo] Warning: com.google.android.gms.fitness.service.FitnessSensorService$a: can't find referenced class android.app.AppOpsManager
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo] Warning: com.google.android.gms.fitness.service.FitnessSensorService$a: can't find referenced class android.app.AppOpsManager
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.af: can't find referenced method 'boolean isAttachedToWindow()' in class android.view.View
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.an$2: can't find referenced method 'void evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,android.webkit.ValueCallback)' in class android.webkit.WebView
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.gu: can't find referenced method 'void evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,android.webkit.ValueCallback)' in class android.webkit.WebView
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo] Warning: there were 11 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo] Warning: there were 3 unresolved references to program class members.
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo]  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo]  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
>   [2015-03-13 02:48:07 - ScoresOnGo]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, order to build the project, proguard requires no warnings.

If you are not using the referenced classes, you can use the `-dontwarn <classname>` flag in your proguard-rules file.

If you just want to try your luck, you can also use the `-ignorewarnings` flag to just ignore all warning and proceed with the build.

See:
http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html

Answer (score -1):

I've never had success exporting apk's from Eclipse with proguard turned on. Since proguard only protects code, not assets I disabled it and stuck my algo's in C++. This complicated stack traces when I got crash reports.

I would prefer Java for these reasons. I would highly recommend writing, and migrating all Java projects in Android Studio. It was effortless to turn proguard on. But as I say, it's only your algo's which it *helps* protect, and much of the algo lifting is done by the Java framework anyway, compared to, say C++ or the NDK.

Possible reasons for failing to export with proguard are importing modules that just won't work and aren't worth fixing to make work. If you're not importing 3rd party modules then you need to instruct proguard to not obfuscate the classes it is not able to find otherwise. I develop more than I release so I refer you to the manual for exact syntax. Just sharing my experience.